# How to make an overlayed stripe gradient with css

Tags: html, css, gradient, overlap, linear-gradients

How do I make a double gradient set of stripes in CSS? Something like this:

```css
.stripe{
background:linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
        rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%,
        rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 21%,
        rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%,
        rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%,
        rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
        rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%,
        rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%,
        rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%,
        rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%
    );}
```

```html
<div class = 'stripe'><h1>.</h1></div>
```

But with an overlay of the opposite degree:

```css
.stripe{
background:linear-gradient(
        -45deg,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
        rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%,
        rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 21%,
        rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%,
        rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%,
        rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
        rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%,
        rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%,
        rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%,
        rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%
    );}
```

```html
<div class = 'stripe'><h1>.</h1></div>
```

If you overlay them it should be something like this:

```css
.stripe {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 10px,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 10px,
        rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 11px,
        rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 12px,
        rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 13px,
        rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 14px,
        rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 15px,
        rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 16px,
        rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 17px,
        rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 18px,
        rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 19px,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 20px
 
  ),
linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
        rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%,
        rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 20%,
        rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%,
        rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%,
        rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
        rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%,
        rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%,
        rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%,
        rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class = 'stripe'><h1>.</h1></div>
```

But this doesen't work because it repeats it over and over. How do I get the pattern to continue and spread out across the whole bar? Note: Without changing the degree amount to negative it would look the same, so I want the overlayed to be -45.

I am asking how to make part of the overlay transparent. I'm trying to figure out how to make 2 gradients; with them overlayed into a stripe pattern.

Comment: Please... read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74041247/383904

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You're trying to add an overlay, to what? You use full opacity `1`... Also, why 10 color stops? Read the first comment's link answer I posted.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Look at the last snippet. I'm attempting to overlay the first and 2nd snippets together, in a stripe pattern.

Comment: As I said... Use alpha opacity 0.5: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/opyu8tea/ The final desired effect is up to you (totally unclear from your question), but hopefully now you know how to set an additional rotated background (slightly transparent) as overlay. If the provided comment does not help, make sure to provide an image of the desired result. "this does not work" is not helpful, and "I want to overlay a background" is already answered.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Something like this: https://i.ibb.co/BNYqvyQ/Screenshot-2023-04-03-16-18-25.png

Comment: That *"something like this"* (exactly like this) is not possible using color stops provided by linear gradient.

Comment: But something similar can be achieved by: 1: including transparent color stops on the overlay; 2: moving the colored stops by a couple of degrees on the overlay. Play with the logic and with some division math (360 / 12 colors and added transparency stops), you can do it - just, it will not look like in the image you provided since it's not possible. To achieve something "almost exactly" like in your image you would perhaps need clip areas... Or SVG...

Answer (score -1):

An opposite degree would be an angle measuring over 180 degrees like this:

```css
.stripe{
    background-size:100% 100%; /*This fills the entire object with the
    gradient, without repetition*/
    background:linear-gradient(
        315deg, /*Instead of -45: 360 - 45 = 315 degrees*/
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
        rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%,
        rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 21%,
        rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%,
        rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%,
        rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
        rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%,
        rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%,
        rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%,
        rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: `21%,` because....